# Map Page<T> to Page<TDto>

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-elasticsearch

Does anyone know the way of mapping one generic Page to another one?
Let's say I have controller which should return Page but service returns Page. How can I convert the Page object returned by service  to Page of other type which is requered by controller?